# Is it possible to use ConfigParser while the headers are not at the beginning of the file?

Tags: python, dictionary, collections, configparser

I have to open a file with this structure

```
Date/time,Field1_avg,Field1_std,Field2_max,Field2_min,Field3_std,Field3_avg
2014-11-19 23:50:00,3.5,0,1,4.8,0.9,9.6,0.75
2014-11-20 23:50:00,4.5,0,1,4.3,0.9,9.1,0.75
2014-11-21 23:50:00,4.5,0,1,4.3,0.9,9.1,0.75
#MOREDATA and before the headers start a line empty
#line empty
[header]
name='blabla'
height=23
[header1]
#and so on
```

Then first line is name of the fields of the table;

From second line to indefinite line data of the table;

Then one line empty;

And finally the diferent headers with the information.

The thing is to read the file, read in a loop the first line and create a table with pandas.

Then get out from the loop and create dictionary with default values, as the information differs from the sections and i want to have at the end a dictionary with the same number of values per key. If the value in the section is not present add '' or 0.

ConfigParser seems to be the best solution to create a dictionary with default values, but the problem is the information at the beginning. It is not a header, then gives an error.

Any Idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Configparser has a `.readfp()` method you can use:

```
import ConfigParser

with open('cfgdata.ini', 'rb') as fp:
    while fp.readline().strip() != "":   # skip all initial lines (or pass them to Pandas..)
        pass

    p = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
    p.readfp(fp)
    print p.sections()
    print p.has_section('header')
```

The only gotcha is that the while loop needs to use `fp.readline()` since that's what `ConfigParser` uses internally.